# jmeter Inter-Thread Communication plugin example jmx not working

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I'm using Jmeter 3.2 without any special plugins.

I just installed Inter-Thread Communication plugin.

I download the [example jmx in plugin page](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) and when I open it I get pop up with the below exception:

I didn't find an issue about it also in [jmeter-plugins](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins).

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.HTTPRawSampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.HTTPRawSampler
line number         : 96
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:442) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.HTTPRawSampler
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:97) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:442) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked only after I installed HTTP Raw request plugin